# Understanding the output of an arithmatic expression

Tags: java

I have a java class as follows:

```
class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int a=10;
       a*=a++ +a;
       System.out.println(a);
    }
}

Output:210
```

In my opinion the `output` should be `231` calculated as follows:

```
a*=10+11;
a*=21;
a=a*21;
a=11*21;
a= 231;
```

Can anyone please explain me where am I wrong and why?

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you consider that `x*=y` is just a shortcut for `x = x * y`, then you can see that it's the original value of `a` which will be used when evaluating the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any statement of the type:

```
x *= y;
```

The initial value of the LHS is evaluated before the RHS. So your statement:

```
a *= a++ + a;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a = a * (a++ + a);
```

Which sets a to the value 10 * (10 + 11) => 210.

If you're particularly interested in the formal specification related to this point you can find it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) which contains the rule "If the operator is a compound-assignment operator (§15.26.2), then evaluation of the left-hand operand includes both remembering the variable that the left-hand operand denotes and fetching and saving that variable's value for use in the implied binary operation."

Answer (score 1):

Consider [15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) section of java specs where it says - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable then the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation indicated by the compound assignment operator

In your case it is a = 10 * ((11)+10) = 201